# Ajax data out of sync with datepicker events

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use $.ajax with php to get event dates from a remote mysql database which takes some amount of time. The idea is to populate jQuery datepicker selectable dates only with those days of the applicable month that contain an event. Trouble is that the datepicker beforeShowDay function triggers before the data is available, making the selections out of sync with onChange events' data retrieval. Is there any way to prevent activating beforeShowDay before the data is available from ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You have synchronize your ajax call.

For that add parameter in ajax call

```
async : false,
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in the past, setting async to false for $.ajax didn't work, but now it does. I must've tripped up somewhere during the problem solution.